# Is there any advantage of displaying list of items as <ol> vs as plain string

Tags: reactjs

I have seen comma separated list of text is begin displayed as `<ol>`/`<ul>` applying some CSS as follow

```
// Sample React Component rendering array items as Ordered List items
function OrderedList({items}) {
  return (
    <ol className='list-inline'>
      {
        items.map((item, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
        })
      }
    </ol>
  );
}

// Sample CSS to remove bullet and separate text with comma 
.list-inline {
    list-style: none;        
}

.list-inline li::after {
    content: ', ';
}

.list-inline li:last-child::after {
    content: none;
}

.list-inline li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Although we could have easily render text as follow

```
function CommonSeperatedText({items}) {
  const itemsAsText = items.join(", ");
  return ( 
    <p>${itemsAsText}</p>
  );
}
```

I was just wondering if there is any advantage of doing as first one?

Comment: Screen readers.  Lists are lists and get read as such to vision impaired users that use screen readers.  Paragraphs are just read flatly.

Comment: An ordered list would define a semantic order to the list items. An unordered list would not. A comma-delimited string would have no explicit semantic information in its structure. "Advantage" would be an opinion of the relative merits of those options.